# GCC compiler does not recognize in the CodeBlocks IDE (Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have been trying to get up and run the C programs in **codeblocks** IDE and it keeps getting me this following error.

```
Checking for existence: /media/darkpheonix/dptech/dptech/Projects/C/techtheory/bin/Debug/techtheory
    Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:
    Executing: xterm -T techtheory -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:. /media/darkpheonix/dptech/dptech/Projects/C/techtheory/bin/Debug/techtheory  (in /media/darkpheonix/dptech/dptech/Projects/C/techtheory/.)
    Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`  
Then tried installing the build essential packages from the main server. `sudo apt-get install build-essentials`.  
This keep getting me following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

I tried different sources but doesn't seem to solve this issue. Please help

Comment: Your [posted] `apt-get` command uses `build-essentials` but your error message complains about `build-essential`. So, the error output is _not_ from the command you posted. I _think_ you want the plural version.

Comment: @CraigEstey I figured out the `build-essential` issue. `sudo apt-get build-essential` worked. Although the path error occurs in **CodeBlcoks**. It requires the path for the `gcc compiler` but i cannot find out a way to export the path since I don't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Solved it!**

### Step 1

#### *GCC compiler configurations*

You have to run the

> `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/sdk/lib"`

to export the path to the compilers.  
Default path is in `usr/bin`  
Copy and paste the path into the `your_lib.conf` file in the location `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` then save and exit.

> `sudo ldconfig`

Run this to confirm the changes in the files which added the paths.

### Step 2

#### *`xterm` configuration*

Install `xterm` into the operating system.

> `sudo apt-get install xterm`

Check and make sure that it is in the latest version of the configurations and then test the **CODEBLOCKS** project, build and run them as console application.